# Rename Changing CSV file name in directory

Tags: python

I have a csv file in which the name will always change when exported from an application. I want to rename the csv file using python. Here's what I have so far, but it's definitely wrong.

```
directory = "/files/"

for file in directory:
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        os.rename('*.csv', 'tracking.csv')
```

Comment: this is more of a pseudo code than a code!

Comment: No idea what you're talking about.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python

Comment: Why can't you change `*.csv` to `file`?

Comment: Since `file` is the source file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i assume you have only one csv file in your directory,

```
import os
directory = "/files/"

files = os.listdir(directory)

# remove the old tracking file if exists
if 'tracking.csv' in files:
    old_file = os.path.join(directory, 'tracking.csv')
    os.unlink(old_file)

# rename
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        os.rename(os.path.join(directory, file), os.path.join(directory, 'tracking.csv'))
        break
```